# regular expressions challenge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to grab only 1 piece of this string:

```
Serving Size: 1 cup, halves, Calories: 48.6, Fat: 0.5g, Carbs: 11.7g, Protein: 1g
```

and many others like it. Although each string will have different variables. For example the string above might look like this:

```
Serving Size: 100 oz, Calories: 48.6, Fat: 0.5g, Carbs: 11.7g, Protein: 1g
```

And so on...

So, I right now I'm trying to get the "oz" or "cup" part of the string ONLY.

The regex I've tried looks something like this:

```
(?<=Serving Size:\s\d*\s)
```

Although in rubular it keeps saying "invalid".

Although if I do

```
(?<=Serving Size:)\s\d*\s
```

It will match the number perfectly... I'm trying to exclude the number and match the measure type.

How can I do this?

Comment: Variable length lookbehind not allowed?

Comment: You would be better off splitting on `,?[ ]*(\w[\w ]*(?<=\w))[ ]*:[ ]*|[ ]*,[ ]*` which gives you all the chunks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this one?

```
s = "Serving Size: 1 cup, halves, Calories: 48.6, Fat: 0.5g, Carbs: 11.7g, Protein: 1g"

regex = /Serving Size:\s*(?<amount>\d+)\s*(?<units>\w+)/

m = s.match(regex) # => #<MatchData "Serving Size: 1 cup" amount:"1" units:"cup">
m['units'] # => "cup"
m['amount'] # => "1"
```

Comment: that includes the number. I'm trying to isolate the measure type.

Comment: The measure type being what? "Serving Size"?

Comment: it's the "oz" or "cup" part of the string. I'd like to be able to isolate that one part and stick it in a variable called "measure_type". The serving size would be the number specifically but I've already been able to isolate that bit.

Comment: @ninja08: so `m['units']` is not good enough for you, huh? Do you need to get the job done or be fancy about it? :)

Comment: Just discovered this `?<variable_name>` syntax, thanks a lot for this Sergio Tulentsev!

Comment: @MrYoshiji: it's called "named capture" if you want to read more about it.

Comment: Actually, your answer is even better than what I was looking for. I didn't know I could create those regex variables like you did here. Thanks for your help! You da man, Sergio!

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answers *why* the regex is not working. Sergio Tulentsev's answer already gives a good solution for *how* to get the desired result.

If I interpret your intent correctly, `(?<=Serving Size:\s\d*\s)` is the look-behind, which I assume is followed by `\w+` or something to match the name of the measurement unit. The problem with your look-behind (and the reason `(?<=Serving Size:)` does work) is that, unlike a look-ahead, a look-behind must have a defined length — including `\d*` causes it to be indefinite.

My recommendation would be to capture the units, then take the needed information from the result. Something like

```
/Serving Size:\s\d*\s(\w+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/Serving Size: (.+), Calories: (.+), Fat: (.+), Carbs: (.+), Protein: (.+)/
```

Use capture groups and then access them with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.